# Изменение свойства обьекта C#

Tags: c#, xaml

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добраться до стиля кнопки (PlayAppBarButtonStyle) и как его изменить через C#. Вот XAML код:

```
<Button Name="but_Play" Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Используйте [`DynamicResource`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf) и выражение вида`:`

    var style = (Style) FindResource("PlayAppBarButtonStyle");

Comment: c Application-a

Comment: @Ev1_Denz: в WPF вручную менять стиль не хочешь ты. Овладей мощью триггеров, юный падаван!

Comment: `-_-` []()